# date format dd.mm.yyyy in C

Tags: c, date, stdin

I want to know if there is a way to read date from console in format dd.mm.yyyy in C. I have a structure with information for the date. I tried with another structure just for the date with  day, month and year in it:

```
typedef struct
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} Date;
```

but the dots are a problem. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please make up your mind whether you want dd/mm/yyyy like in the title or dd.mm.yyyy like in the question?

Comment: you could just read a string from console and parse it yourself, that way to will check if a certain month has x days or month var is lower than 13 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
  Date d;
  if (scanf("%d.%d.%d", &d.day, &d.month, &d.year) != 3)
    error();
```

Comment: `Date` is a type, not a variable; I took the liberty to fix. +1 for checking return of scanf.

Comment: @Jens: you're right, thanks (I missed the `typedef`) -- @Paulpro: `error()` could display an error message, and exit..

Comment: do i need to malloc memory for every date information ? because i tried it that way but when im showing the main structure the info for the date is 00.00.0000

Comment: This heavily depends on your program, and without source code I can't say anything..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) to read in an arbitrary formatted date string into a `struct tm`.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE /* glibc2 needs this to have strptime(). */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

...

Date d = {0};
char * fmt = "%d.%m.%Y";
char s[32] = "";
char fmt_scanf[32] = "";
int n = 0;

sprintf(fmt_scanf, "%%%ds", sizeof(s) - 1); /* Created format string for scanf(). */

errno = 0;    
if (1 == (n = scanf(fmt_scanf, s)))
{
  struct tm t = {0};
  char * p = strptime(s, fmt, &t);
  if ((s + strlen(s)) != p)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid date: '%s'\n", s);
  }
  else
  {
    d.day = t.tm_mday;
    d.month = t.tm_mon + 1; /* tm_mon it zero-based. */
    d.year = t.tm_year + 1900; /* tm_year is years since 1900. */ 
  }
}
else
{
  perror("scanf()");
}
```

**Update**:

The positive side effects and addtional gains of going this way are:

- No input validation is necessary, as it's all done by `strptime()`.
- Changing the input format is trivial: Just let `fmt` point to a different format string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a function defined in  just for the purpose: strftime()!
(Thank you tutorialpoints.com for giving details on the standard libraries of C)

What does it do? It allows us to create a string with *as much of* date and/or time as we want, *howsoever* we want it to have them, and also other characters to the string if needed! For an example, we can create a "20191011.log" string for instance, if we wanted to say make a filename for today's log.

Here is the code required for just this:

```
#include<stdio.h>//printf
#include<time.h>//localtime,time,strftime


/*Here, the log file's name will be created*/
int main()  
{
    char filename[13];
    //Obtaining time
    time_t raw;
    struct tm *obtained_time;

    time(&raw);
    obtained_time = localtime (&raw);


    //Obtaining string_format out of generated time
    int success_filename;

    success_filename = strftime(filename,sizeof(filename),"%Y%m%d.log",obtained_time);//yyyymmdd.log
    if (success_filename != 0)
    {
            printf("%s",filename);
    }
    obtained_time = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

`

The third argument of strftime is where you can make your recipe of strings, and there are a whole lot of options, such as abbreviated or full names of days and months, time, seconds, hours, minutes, AM/PM designation etc. To explore them more, go to the following link:
[Tutorialspoint on strftime() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm)

Do let me know if it helps you out!