# How to set the width of the format specifier for a variable type char array in C?

Tags: c

I have a function --

```
bool DataPersistence::persistUIDetails (const char *data, quint32 len)
{
  TLOG_FUNC_ENTER();
  bool retVal = true;

  char tmp[len+1];
  strncpy (tmp, data, len);

  //Working on persisting the UI details.
  char type[len];
  char uiVers[len];
  char mwVers[len];
  char ts[len];

  sscanf (tmp, "%s %s %s %s", type, uiVers, mwVers, ts);

}
```

I want to put a maximum width for this format specifier. How can I do so in C?

Something like %255S

Comment: Well...it's %ns where n is the number of chars. Example: %25s

Comment: It's a variable length. It's not set to 255. You can see the function accepts the length parameter.

Comment: Do you mean that no matter the length of the string, you only want to scan at most 255 characters? Then what's wrong with doing exactly `"%255s"`? Or do you mean that the width is variable? Anyway, I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Also consider std::string and std::stringstream: They exactly do what you want in and in a safer manner, too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: the question *was* tagged C++ (which vscoftco removed) *and* C - you can see the function's a class member, so black''s suggestions reasonable.

Comment: `strncpy (tmp, data, len);` is probably a mistake. You need to null-terminate `tmp`. Also it's not clear whether `len` is the actual length of the input text, or a maximum possible length .

Comment: An example on how to create a format string a runtine can also be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16761735/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sprintf to print the format string:

```
char formatString[256];
sprintf(formatString, "%%%ds %%%ds %%%ds %%%ds", len, len, len, len);
```

Then use it in sscanf:

```
sscanf (tmp, formatString, type, uiVers, mwVers, ts);
```

Comment: In general, when using this approach, take care not to allow buffer overflows of `formatString` itself. For example use `snprintf` and check its return value.